# Canonical base of polynomial (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

I am learning Linear Algebra for few months in school, and I not understand how polynomials works in Linear spaces. Sorry if my nomenclature is different from english one, because I am translating it from Czech.

I have two basis defined as so:

```
B = (x^2, x, 1)
C = (x^2 + 3x − 2, x − 2, 1)
```

I know how to convert these to matrices but I don't know if its right

C will be:

```
| 1  0  0|
| 3  1  0|
|-2 -2  1|
```

B will be:

```
| 1  0  0|
| 0  1  0|
| 0  0  1|
```

Is this right? Or I must compute with polynomials different way

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! It's correct (the first is the matrix of basis C expressed in basis B).

Comment: @Bernard Hi, thanks. So There is not rule that Canonical base in polynomial is (1,x,x^2,...)? I am getting mixed answers from wikipedia etc

Comment: It is the usual one, but that depends on the problem to solve. For instance, in problems of integer-valued polynomials, one often uses the binomial basis: $\{1, x,\frac{x(x-1)}2\}$.

Comment: @Bernard So in your example basis is what then in matrix

Comment: If the order of the vectors is the one I gave, it is $\;\begin{bmatrix}0&0 &\frac12\\0&1&-\frac12\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$.